# Filter pivot table based on another pivot table filter on a different sheet with a different data source

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot, pivot-table

I have 2 different pivot tables on different Excel sheets using different data sources. They both have a "Style" column that can be filtered. When I filter for style on one pivot table I want the other pivot table to automatically (or with a button) filter for those same selected styles.

I am currently working on this code I found on a different forum. In the objects section in VBA I have:

```
Sub ChangePivotFilter()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim aWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim myPivot As Excel.PivotTable
Dim myPivotField As Excel.PivotField
Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
For Each WS In aWB.Worksheets
For Each myPivot In WS.PivotTables

Set myPivotField = Nothing

On Error Resume Next

Set myPivotField = myPivot.PivotFields(“Style”)

myPivotField.CurrentPage = “Style”

Next myPivot

Next WS

End Sub
```

In the module section in VBA I have:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim s$

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
    With ThisWorkbook.PivotTables
        Let s = .Item("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Style").CurrentPage
        .Item("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Style").ClearAllFilters
        .Item("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Style").CurrentPage = s
    End With
Else
    With ThisWorkbook.PivotTables
        Let s = .Item("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Style").CurrentPage
        .Item("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Style").ClearAllFilters
        .Item("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Style").CurrentPage = s
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the comment dwirony! I edited my original post and added some code I have been working with. Is there any chance that you could be of some assistance?